# Why does this query give me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, dotconnect

This code:

```
string SidFinch = "Unknown SidFinch";

String sql = @"SELECT SidFinch 
           FROM PlatypusDuckbillS 
           WHERE PlatypusSTARTDATE = :Duckbilldate AND 
                   DuckbillID = :Duckbillid";
try {
    using (OracleCommand ocmd = new OracleCommand(sql, oc)) {
        ocmd.Parameters.Add("Duckbilldate", DuckbillDate);
        ocmd.Parameters.Add("Duckbillid", DuckbillID);
        SidFinch = ocmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
```

...fails on the "ExecuteScalar" line. It's not finding anything (there is no matching record for the ID I passed), but that shouldn't cause this problem, should it?

Comment: Just saying... dapper... http://pastie.org/4003886

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it doesn't find anything - then presumably `.ExecuteScalar()` is returning `NULL` and it's not a good idea to call `.ToString()` on a `NULL` ....

You need to change your code to be something like:

```
object result =  ocmd.ExecuteScalar();

if(result != null)
{
    SidFinch = result.ToString();
} 
else
{
     // do whatever is appropriate here....
}
```

Comment: If I omit the ".ToString()" I get, "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: That's because SidFinch is a string. Do a null check before you convert to string.

Comment: @Clay yes, but it depends on what type `SidFinch` is, and whether it can be null. Either a cast `(string)ocmd.ExecuteScalar()` or `Convert.ToString(ocmd.ExecuteScalar())` should work.

Comment: you can use SidFinch = ocmd.ExecuteScalar() as string, and then to check if its not a null. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999020/handling-executescalar-when-no-results-are-returned) kinda resembles your question

Comment: @Marc: Yes, Convert.ToString(ocmd.ExecuteScalar()); works. So does UCID = (String)ocmd.ExecuteScalar(); The Marcs are really on it.