# How to get Last entry of Particular ID

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Below is my query I want to fetch last entry of `visitno` ,of particular `pid`,this query works fine but selects all rows of pid ,`visistNo is of Number Datatype`

```
public int GetPatientID_visitNo(int pid)
    {
        int data = 0;
        try
        {
            string sql = "Select VisitNo From Patient_Visit_Details where Patient_ID = " + pid;
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, acccon);
            rs = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rs.HasRows)
            {
                data = Convert.ToInt32(rs[0]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
        }
        return data;
    }
```

when I try below Query it gives me error `no data exist` since my table is new and it dosn't contain any row ,how I can Do this

```
string sql = "Select MAX(VisitNo) From Patient_Visit_Details where Patient_ID = " + pid;
```

Comment: That is no error. Just use `1` then.

Comment: 1 ? please explore your answer more

Comment: What do you need the max() value for?

Comment: I want to Make `VisistNO` column as autoIncrement for Particular ID ,so I am trying to Fetch Last entry of `visitNo` so that I can increment  it by 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string sql = string.Format(@"SELECT TOP 1 VisitNo
                             FROM patient_Visit_Details
                             WHERE Patient_ID = {0}
                             ORDER BY VisitNo DESC", pid);
```

Also, use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` for this.  Check the return value for when there are no rows.

Note also,  that if `pid` has arrived from somewhere outside your application (e.g. a web page), your sql is open to [Injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Now, as has been pointed out - what if there are no rows?  See this question here: [Handling ExecuteScalar() when no results are returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999020/handling-executescalar-when-no-results-are-returned), the ethos being - check for `null` and `DbNull.Value` before trying to convert to an `Int32`.

Comment: @juergend, if I read his question correctly, he wants the latest (highest?) `VisitNo` for a given patient?  Or have I read the question incorrectly?

Comment: The problem is that if no value exists for a given patient he gets no result.

Answer (score 1):

change SQL statement as beloe

```
string sql = "Select ISNULL(MAX(VisitNo), 0)  From Patient_Visit_Details where Patient_ID = " + pid;
```

use `ExecuteScalar` and add validation for null result

```
var maxVisit = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

if (maxVisit != null && maxVisit != DBNull.Value) 
{
   data = Convert.ToInt32(maxVisit);
}
```