# custom validator always retriving true even when it is not

Tags: c#, sql-server

The C# Code:

```
string str = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;";
str += "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DinoData.mdf;";
str += "Integrated Security= True";

SqlConnection c;
c = new SqlConnection(str);
SqlCommand Cdd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [User] WHERE UserName LIKE @Username;", c);
Cdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtuser.Text);
c.Open();
int NameExist = (int)Cdd.ExecuteScalar();
c.Close();
if (NameExist > 0)
{
    CVName.IsValid = true;

    if ((bool)Session["Conect"])
    {
        SqlCommand getlev = new SqlCommand("SELECT level FROM [User] WHERE Username like @user", c);
        getlev.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtuser.Text);
        c.Open();
        int a = (int)getlev.ExecuteScalar();
        c.Close();
        if (a>5)
        {
            CVSemi.IsValid = false;
            if (a >= 10)
            {
                CVmax.IsValid = false;
            }
            else
                CVmax.IsValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            CVSemi.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    CVName.IsValid = false;
    txtuser.CssClass = "err";
}
if (Page.IsValid)
{
    /*Something happen*/
}
```

The validator CVmax always true
even when I turned the if to:
 `if (a >= 1)`

I update the code the CVmax is always valid why??
I tried to do every thing but without success please help

Comment: Can you at least format your code properly?

Comment: Have you debugged if the control is entering into `if (a >= 10)`? What initial value have to provided to CVmax?

Comment: `The validator CVmax always true even when I turned the if to:  if (a >= 1)` What value does `a` have when you step through your code in a debugger?

Comment: Leaving your problem aside for a second, you really need to learn how C# code is written. You are missing `using` statements and your way to initialize/name objects shows lack of knowledge. Have you even tried to see what value the Database actually has?

Comment: Side note: For the love of unmanaged resources, please use the `using` statement for things that are IDisposable. If the line with ExecuteScalar throws an exception for any reason, the connection will never be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd run the debugger to be sure, but are you sure it's not skipping the second `if`?

```
if (NameExist > 0) {
CVName.IsValid = true;  // here you set the value to true.

// supposing this if doesn't trigger, CVmax will stay true.
    if ((bool)Session["Conect"])
    {
        SqlCommand getlev = new SqlCommand("SELECT level FROM [User] WHERE Username like @user", c);
        getlev.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtuser.Text);
         c.Open();
         int a = (int)getlev.ExecuteScalar();
         c.Close();

         if (a>5){
             CVSemi.IsValid = false;

             if (a >= 10) {
                 CVmax.IsValid = false;
              }
              else {
                   CVmax.IsValid = true;
              }
          else
          {
                CVSemi.IsValid = true;
           }
    else
    {
        CVName.IsValid = false;
        txtuser.CssClass = "err";
    }
```

As @DavidG says, you code is formatted poorly. After organizing it a bit, it looks like some of your IFs aren't even hitting. In the snippet you gave there not alternative for the `NameExist > 0` bit so all that needs to be entered is a correct user name...

So, to be brutally honest, scrap the code and start fresh with proper formatting and `Using`.

Answer (score -1):

Been awhile since I used something other than an ORM, but I'd make the following suggestions:

1)  Review how you are handling the ExecuteScalar response, see [here]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1999031/6415885

2)  Since a null response is a distinct possibility here, is the boxing of ExecuteScalar, forcing a 0 response?

```
 int a = (int)getlev.ExecuteScalar();
```

or should it be

```
int? a = (int?)getlev.ExecuteScalar();
 if (a != null)
 {
      if (a==0) {CVmax.IsValid = false;}
 }
 else
 {
      CVmax.IsValid = false
 }
```

Comment: No, no, no! Don't suggest SQL like this - it is highly vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: And with "'%' + @user + '%'" as the like a user could input a generic single character (say "a") and it would find many matches depending on the size of the user db. Won't work and is very dangerous.

Comment: Removed suggestion