# ExecuteScalar() return error "Specified cast is not valid." when there is no record

Tags: c#, ado.net

i have used below code for calculating (total invoice) each customer, for customers there is no invoice , it return error , i tried to handle error with null but it does not work.

```
   public static decimal GetInvoiceTotal(int customerID)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = MMABooksDB.GetConnection();
        string selectStatement
            = "SELECT SUM(InvoiceTotal) "
            + "FROM Invoices "
            + "WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID";
        SqlCommand selectCommand =
            new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection);
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", customerID);




        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            if (selectCommand.ExecuteScalar()!=null)
            {
                decimal invoiceTotal = (decimal)selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                return invoiceTotal;
            }


            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are casting to decimal? Also, you should modify your code  to use ExecuteScalar only once.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999020/handling-executescalar-when-no-results-are-returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to call the `ExecuteScalar` twice.

```
var value = selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
if(value != DBNull.Value)
{
    return (decimal)value;
}
```

**Update**

In broad strokes, the `DBNull` class represents a non existing value. It's different from the `null`, which means the absence of a reference to an object. So When the result of an sql query is `NULL`, the value that is returned by `ADO.NET` (it's the technology you used to access the database) is `DBNull`.

For further info, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.110).asp%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bx).

Comment: i changed my code like your answer, i checked with debug var value is {} and it passes condition if(value!=null), i do not know how it passes  if(value!=null)

Comment: yet does not work, i do not know what means when value={}, and is not null.

Comment: @Masoud for debugging, please do this, before the return statement, add the following statement `var temp = value.ToString();` and tell me what is the value of `temp`. Thanks

Comment: temp returns ""

Comment: type of value is System.DBNull and value of that is {}

Comment: thanks alot, it works, i did not understand difference between (DBNull.Value) and null and when to use them?

Comment: You are welcome :) A detailed explanation of why this works can be found here, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.110).aspx. In broad strokes, the `DBNull ` class represents a non existing value. It's different from the `null`, which means the absence of a reference to an object. So When the result of an sql query is `NULL`, the value that is returned by ADO.NET (it's the technology you used to access the database) is `DBNull`.

Comment: @Christos, I believe your answer will be even better if you include your last comment into it as an explanation for the solution.