# How to solve null in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a method to show a value in a `TextBox`:

```
public double sumaEntregasDos(int id)
{
    conectar();
    //cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(pc.entrega) FROM PagosClientes pc INNER JOIN Clientes c ON pc.idCliente = c.idCliente WHERE c.nombre = @nombreCliente";
    //cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombreCliente", nombre);

    cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(entrega) FROM PagosClientes WHERE idCliente in (" + 
        id + ")";

    double suma = Convert.ToDouble(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
    desconectar();
    return suma;
}
```

When I press the Button, the program shows me the following error:

> Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: One solution may be to provide a NULL value condition in case that the sum on entrega is not able to be calculated.

Comment: I don't know how, 'cause the problem is in the line `double suma = Convert.ToDouble(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling ExecuteScalar() when no results are returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999020/handling-executescalar-when-no-results-are-returned)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way is to check for `DBNull`:

```cs
var result = cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
return result == DBNull.Value ? default : (double)result;
```

It's a bit cumbersome, so often it's easier to just write `SELECT ISNULL(..., 0) ...`

Further points:

- This only applies if you get an actual `NULL` result. If there are **no rows at all** then you need to check for `null` instead of `DBNull.Value`
- If you do have a null value you need to handle, the above code also works for `double?`
- Obviously use your commented out code instead which uses parameters properly, instead  of the code you actually have. Please note that [`AddWithValue` is evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), you should specify the actual `SqlDbType`, although in the case of `int` it doesn't really matter.
- It looks like you are caching your connection object. You should not do this. Instead, [create it on the spot, and dispose it in a `using` block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552829/c-sharp-data-connections-best-practice).